# Genexus EV3 father-son

Tags: genexus

I'm currently using the EV3. I have a father-son inheritance using subtypes. I need to save a daughter transaction. But to register the child transaction you must be created before the parent transaction (generated key). what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that when you create the daughter, the father doesn´t exist yet?

I guess you have a transaction "Person" or something like that.

You could have a transaction "FatherChild" with the attributes "FatherId" (subtipe of Person), and "ChildId" (subtipe of Person). 
So like this you can create first the Father or the Son/Daughter, in any order. And then you just create a FatherChild selecting the father and the child.

If I didnt get your question well, please try to write it somehow different.